# Determine row size for table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to I determine the maximum row size for a table? I'm looking for a tool or script that does this so I don't have to add up each column's size by hand.

My goal is to produce a report of tables that are too wide so we can look into restructing them. I know we have several that are so wide that only 1 row fits on each 8K page, but I want to find the rest.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Another way, run this then look at MaximumRecordsize

```
dbcc showcontig ('YourTableNameHere') with tableresults
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this appears to only show the maximum record size of the current data, not the maximum potential record size.

Comment: This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175008.aspx

Comment: both this and the answer of @gotqn below give a value of 0 for all ..._record_size_in_bytes, when the table is empty. if i read OP correctly, it is asking for the *potential* row size - if the actual maximum was exceeded, the record would fail to store anyway.

Answer (score 43):

As the [DBCC SHOWCONTIG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175008.aspx) is going to be deprecated, `Microsoft` advises to use the [sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx) instead. You can get the maximum, minimum and average row size for each index and other stats, too:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(N'AdventureWorks2014'), OBJECT_ID(N'[sales].[SalesOrderHeader]'), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED')
```

Output:

```
database_id object_id   index_id    partition_number index_type_desc                                              alloc_unit_type_desc                                         index_depth index_level avg_fragmentation_in_percent fragment_count       avg_fragment_size_in_pages page_count           avg_page_space_used_in_percent record_count         ghost_record_count   version_ghost_record_count min_record_size_in_bytes max_record_size_in_bytes avg_record_size_in_bytes forwarded_record_count compressed_page_count
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------- ------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ---------------------------- -------------------- -------------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------ -------------------- -------------------- -------------------------- ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ---------------------- ---------------------
6           1266103551  1           1                CLUSTERED INDEX                                              IN_ROW_DATA                                                  3           0           0.439882697947214            28                   24.3571428571429           682                  98.8644304423029               31465                0                    0                          154                      195                      171.487                  NULL                   0
6           1266103551  1           1                CLUSTERED INDEX                                              IN_ROW_DATA                                                  3           1           0                            2                    1                          2                    54.7442550037064               682                  0                    0                          11                       11                       11                       NULL                   0
6           1266103551  1           1                CLUSTERED INDEX                                              IN_ROW_DATA                                                  3           2           0                            1                    1                          1                    0.296515937731653              2                    0                    0                          11                       11                       11                       NULL                   0
6           1266103551  2           1                NONCLUSTERED INDEX                                           IN_ROW_DATA                                                  2           0           0                            4                    25.5                       102                  99.0670990857425               31465                0                    0                          24                       24                       24                       NULL                   0
6           1266103551  2           1                NONCLUSTERED INDEX                                           IN_ROW_DATA                                                  2           1           0                            1                    1                          1                    31.4801087225105               102                  0                    0                          23                       23                       23                       NULL                   0
6           1266103551  3           1                NONCLUSTERED INDEX                                           IN_ROW_DATA                                                  2           0           0                            3                    36.3333333333333           109                  99.8363355572029               31465                0                    0                          26                       26                       26                       NULL                   0
6           1266103551  3           1                NONCLUSTERED INDEX                                           IN_ROW_DATA                                                  2           1           0                            1                    1                          1                    36.3355572028663               109                  0                    0                          25                       25                       25                       NULL                   0
6           1266103551  4           1                NONCLUSTERED INDEX                                           IN_ROW_DATA                                                  2           0           0                            2                    27.5                       55                   98.9285025945145               31465                0                    0                          12                       12                       12                       NULL                   0
6           1266103551  4           1                NONCLUSTERED INDEX                                           IN_ROW_DATA                                                  2           1           0                            1                    1                          1                    11.527057079318                55                   0                    0                          15                       15                       15                       NULL                   0
6           1266103551  5           1                NONCLUSTERED INDEX                                           IN_ROW_DATA                                                  2           0           0                            2                    27.5                       55                   98.9285025945145               31465                0                    0                          12                       12                       12                       NULL                   0
6           1266103551  5           1                NONCLUSTERED INDEX                                           IN_ROW_DATA                                                  2           1           0                            1                    1                          1                    13.5656041512231               55                   0                    0                          18                       18                       18                       NULL                   0
```

Comment: Note that if table has no rows then `max_record_size_in_bytes = 0` so it's not giving the theoretical max bytes which is what OP wants.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another query I got, but like Tomalak's it is broken because it doesn't take into account things like the overhead for variable length columns.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME (id) tablename
     , COUNT (1)        nr_columns
     , SUM (length)     maxrowlength
FROM   syscolumns
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME (id)
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME (id)
```

Comment: What about (N)VARCHAR columns?

Answer (score 5):

Might not the best but this is showing the number of rows + for columns with datatype date,time and so on

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN  sysobjects so on t.object_id = so.id
INNER JOIN  syscolumns SC on (so.id = sc.id)
INNER JOIN systypes st on (st.type = sc.type)
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
    AND so.type = 'U'
and st.name IN ('DATETIME', 'DATE', 'TIME')
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    p.rows DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. You can add the size of each column in a table to give you an idea which tables have the potential to overshoot the 8k/row rule.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

You will figure out the rest when you see the query result.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more accurate. That requires hand-keying all the overhead for variable length fields, nullable bits, and the like.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't aware of dbcc showcontig having the data tailored already. SQLMenace's answer is much better. This one is hardly a down-vote, though.

Comment: For a nvarchar column, its CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH and CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH are both -1, what does that mean?

Comment: @machinarium That means that there is no defined maximum length because these columns have been declared as [`NVARCHAR(MAX)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) (which means they can store [up to 2GB of data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11131977/18771)).

Answer (score 2):

Better option to get table size

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

Comment: @downvoter can you please explain what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. He's asking for a script that tells you the theoretical maximum row size per table, your answer gives actual stats on each table's size, but nothing about maximum row size.