# calculate each row size of the table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have output like this (200 rows) and i want to calculate the data size of each row at the end.

```
id    Name   city  Country phoneNumber DataSize

1      A      B     C       123456      ?
2      A      B     C       123456      ? 
3      A      B     C       123456      ?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine row size for table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496413/determine-row-size-for-table)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. it will change based on things like storage and compression options