# Is there a query to find average Variable Data Size in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to calculate total row size for a table, whose formula is

`row_size = Fixed data size + variable data size + null bitmap +4`.

for this I am trying to find the average variable data size through query in `SQL`. Is there a query that can be used in `SQL` which would achieve this?

Comment: how do you define variable data size? if is varchar instead of char? if it so then select the varchar column and use AVG(LEN(Column)) function to get the average length.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496413/determine-row-size-for-table and this http://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2013/07/calculate-sql-row-size.html

Answer (score 0):

not a complete answer, but how about something like this

build dynamic sql from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  table - 
you could maybe introduce your own flag to flag variable/non-variable length fields.

Building the SQL using a cursor is an option too

```
--data lengths of each table

    DECLARE @SQLa as nvarchar(max) ='';
    select @SQLa = @SQLa + 
                        'SELECT COALESCE(DATALENGTH(['+ Column_Name +']), 0) as dlen, ''' 
                        + Column_Name 
                        + ''' colname, ''' 
                        + Table_name 
                        + ''' tabname  FROM [' 
                        +  Table_name 
                        + '] UNION ALL ' FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  

    SELECT @SQLa = LEFT(@SQLa, LEN(@SQLa) -10)

    SELECT @SQLa = 'SELECT DQ.tabname, SUM(DQ.dlen) as TotalLen FROM (' + @SQLa + ') DQ GROUP BY tabname'

    select @SQLa;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqla;
```